# Mysql decrement values of a single row if they are greater than something

Tags: mysql, request, sql-update, row

I would like to know how I could do this:

I have a Mysql table with dozens of columns that I would like to update. But this update concerns all columns of a single row.
So I need to update each of the columns of that particular row so that if their value is greater than a reference, they should be decreased by 1.

So far, all I could come up with is something like this but, obviously, it's a heresy:

```
    $sql= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET columnA = columnA-1 WHERE (columnA > ".$val." AND id = 1 ");
    $sql= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET columnB = columnB-1 WHERE (columnB > ".$val." AND id = 1 ");  
    $sql= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET columnC = columnC-1 WHERE (columnC > ".$val." AND id = 1 ");
    .....(22 times)....
    $sql= mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET columnZ = columnZ-1 WHERE (columnZ > ".$val." AND id = 1 ");
```

So:

1) Is the syntax ok to fulfill my requirement (lower by 1 if the value is greater than $val?

2): How could I do not to access the database so many times JUST to update all columns of a single row? is it only possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    columnA = CASE WHEN columnA > val THEN columnA - 1 ELSE columnA END,
    columnB = CASE WHEN columnB > val THEN columnB - 1 ELSE columnB END,
    columnC = CASE WHEN columnC > val THEN columnC - 1 ELSE columnC END,
    ...
WHERE
    id = 1;
```

This solution also eliminates the problem of making so many separate round trips to and from the database.  Instead, then above update would execute as as single statement/transaction.

Comment: Thank you, that's way better and it seems to fit my needs!
The "END" part doesn't function like a "break/return false", right?

Comment: Of course but it asks for 8 minutes before I can mark as solved. I added a small question in my last comment, could you help? Thanks!